# mysql select last 5 records from first 50 records in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select last 5 records from first 50 records in the table, currently i have following query, somebody tell me best way to select these records without calculating the limit and offset?

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE enabled=1 ORDER BY date LIMIT 5, 45
```

Comment: `LIMIT 45, 5`..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50) AS tbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) as tbldata ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

this works:

> SELECT id FROM (SELECT id,date FROM table ORDER BY date LIMIT 50) AS
>   temptable ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5